# Hadoop : Filenotfound exception - windows

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce

This problem seems to be already raised in Stackoverflow, but my case is quite different, file or folder location hadoop looking for is created in `C:/tmp/hadoop-SYSTEM/mapred/local/taskTracker/jobcache/`, in this location job folder are created while run the wordcount example, but even the files and folder are avalilable, its throwing the file not found exception, it seems like files not been identified, i even tried the `re-formating of namenode` which is one of the solution provided in forums,but still problem exist

`Note: Hadoop version 0.20.2`

ERROR:

```
13/04/11 10:24:20 WARN conf.Configuration: DEPRECATED: hadoop-site.xml found in the classpath. Usage of hadoop-site.xml is deprecated. Instead use core-site.xml, mapred-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml to override properties of core-default.xml, mapred-default.xml and hdfs-default.xml respectively
13/04/11 10:24:21 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
13/04/11 10:24:21 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
13/04/11 10:24:22 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201304111023_0001
13/04/11 10:24:23 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
13/04/11 10:24:34 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201304111023_0001_m_000002_0, Status : FAILED
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File C:/tmp/hadoop-SYSTEM/mapred/local/taskTracker/jobcache/job_201304111023_0001/attempt_201304111023_0001_m_000002_0/work/tmp does not exist.
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:361)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:245)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.setupWorkDir(TaskRunner.java:519)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:155)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the permissions to that folder have been set properly, this type of error may occur if write permissions are not given to that folder.

Comment: Can you post your program code,Cant get anything else from the errors